# Formula for $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k+b_k x$, $0\leq b_k\leq 1$ and $a_k = 1- b_k$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Is there a nice formula for the polynomial $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k+b_k x$, with the additional assumption that $0\leq b_k\leq 1$ and  $a_k =1- b_k$. I tried to write out the formula explicitly and already got really messy for $n=3$.

For $n=2$, we have 
$$(1-b_1)(1-b_2) + (b_1 + b_2 - 2 b_1 b_2) x + b_1 b_2 x^2$$
and for $n=3$, we have 
$$(1-b_1)(1-b_2)(1-b_3) + \\
\Big[b_1+b_2+b_3 - 2(b_1b_2 + b_1 b_3+b_2 b_3) + 2 b_1 b_2 b_3\Big] x +\\
\Big[b_1b_2 + b_1 b_3 +b_2 b_3 - 3 b_1b_2b_3 \Big]x^2+\\
\Big[b_1b_2b_3 \Big]x^3$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_k(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ denote the $k$th symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables: $$e_k(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = \sum_{S \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}} [|S| = k] \prod_{s \in S} X_s$$

Substitute $y = x-1$ to get $$\prod_{k=1}^n 1 + b_k y$$

This is equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^n e_k(b_1,\ldots,b_n) y^k$$
Now we can undo the substitution to get $$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{k=0}^n e_k(b_1,\ldots,b_n) (x - 1)^k
& = & \sum_{k=0}^n e_k(b_1,\ldots,b_n) \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k+j} \binom{k}{j} x^{j} \\
& = & \sum_{j=0}^n x^{j} \sum_{k=j}^n (-1)^{j+k} \binom{k}{j} e_k(b_1,\ldots,b_n)  \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Each of the terms in the sum which makes up the coefficient of $x^j$ has a different order of symmetric polynomial, so I suspect that it can't be simplified any further.

Note that you seem to have an error in your calculated expression for $n=3$: $2b_1 b_2 b_3$ shouldn't occur as a term, because $2$ is not equal to $\binom{3}{j}$ for any $j$. It should be $\binom{3}{2} = 3$, not $2$.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is suppose to to be $3$.